# Windows kernel driver development: Log |DbgPrint()| output to a file

Tags: debugging, winapi, windbg, windows-driver

We want to automagically print all messages from a Windows kernel module (e.g. [DbgPrint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgprint)) to a Cygwin terminal or file, without any GUI involved.

Options which do not work:

- cdb has `!dbgprint`, but running it in an endless loop consumes lots of CPU time, and in case the kernel buffer is empty it prints that information
- [DebugView](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/DebugView.zip) can log to a file, but has a GUI and cannot be scripted

Is there any other way ?

We tried cdb and DebugView, but both do not work for us

Comment: Type dbgview /? and you see all options to autmatically start dbgview and log to file.
Otherwise write your own OutputDebugString accdeptor. Just google, how OutputDebugString works.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugevent

Comment: Have you read through [Configuring Exceptions and Events in CDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/configuring-exceptions-and-events-in-cdb)? That allows you to respond to specific events (such as debug output).

Comment: [`.logopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-logopen--open-log-file-) opens a log file where everything is outputted to a file. You can limit what goes to the output with [`.outmask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debuggercmds/-outmask--control-output-mask-).